# Mix Panel API web segmentation and personalisation

Tags: mixpanel, personalization

Hi I am interested in using Mix Panel on a web site to track customers events. I would like to know if there is any way to use the api to personalise the web site per customer, similar to segmentation for emails.

I would like to query the api for a singular customer asking whether they have achieved several events.

For example something like

If customer has clicked out and last visit greater than a month ago display a banner advert.

Answer (score 1):

Mixpanel does not seem like a correct tool for the job you describe here.

While theoretically this might be possible (via Mixpanel's HTTP API), this will create unnecessary architectural complexity and add extra latency. If you need to customize your web site per user, store any user state in a database like MySQL or PostgreSQL. This will be both faster and easier.